# Why does $u$ belong to $L^1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm reading an article of second order gradient like-system $$u^{\prime\prime}+Bu^\prime+\nabla F(u) = 0. \tag{1.1}$$

[image]

(here $U_t$ is similar to $u^\prime$ in the above equation)

I don't understand why the author could conclude "$||U_t||^2\in L^1$". I think we can only say that $U_t(t)$ has a finit limit as $t$ tends to infinity.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You have the equation $\frac{1}{2}||U_t(t)||^2- \frac{1}{2}||U_t(0)||^2+ \int_0^t\left<g(U_s(s)),U_s\right> ds= F(U(t))- F(U(0))$  which is, of course, the same as $\frac{1}{2}||U_t(t)||^2= F(U(t))- F(U(0))+ \frac{1}{2}||U_t(0)||^2- \int_0^t\left<g(U_s(s)),U_s\right> ds$.  Since everything on the right is finite, so is the left.

Comment: @user247327 yes that's right, but $||u||^2\in L^1$ iff $\int_0^\infty ||u||^2 < \infty$, not $||u||^2 < \infty$.